# Python : Hang Man game

Tags: python

I am making a hang man game. I am trying to cycle through a word and have all the repeats in the letter be appended to my list. For example the word "hello": if the user types in "l" I want all the l's to be added to my list. Right now it is only finding one "l" and if the user types an "l" again it finds the second "l".

I also want the user not to be able to type in another letter if they previously already typed it in.

I have two lists one for right guesses and wrong guesses that store every guess. For example if a user types in "h" in "hello"

"h" is a right guess so it appends to [h] but if they type in "h" again it adds it to the list so it says ["h","h"]. The wrong box works the same way but for words that are wrong. If they type in "z" for the word "hello" it says ["z"] in the wrong box.

Here is my code:

```
import random

user_input = ""

turns = 5

print("Welcome to Advanced Hang Man!")

print("Use your brain to unscramble the word without seeing its order!")

words = ["hello","goolge","czar","gnat","relationship","victor","patric","gir","foo","cheese"]

# Picks a random word from the list and prints the length of it
random_word = (random.choice(words))

random_word_legnth = (len(random_word))

print("Hint! The length of the word is",random_word_legnth)

hold_random_word = [i for i in random_word]    

while turns != 0 and set(right_guess) != set(hold_random_word):

user_input  = input("Please type your guess one letter at a time:")

right_guess = []
wrong_guess = []

#Calculating every input
if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input.isalpha():
    for i in user_input:
        if i in hold_random_word:
            right_guess.append(i)
        else:
            wrong_guess.append(i)

    print("Correct guess", ''.join(right_guess))
    print("Wrong guess", ''.join(wrong_guess))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input.isalpha():
    for i in user_input:
        if i in hold_random_word and i not in right_guess:
            right_guess.append(i)
        elif i not in hold_random_word or i not in wrong_guess:
            wrong_guess.append(i)
        elif i in hold_random_word:
            # here user types something that is already typed and is a right_guess
            pass
        else:
            # Types something wrong, that was already typed
            pass

    print("Correct guess", ''.join(right_guess))
    print("Wrong guess", ''.join(wrong_guess))
```

It is not clear how you are taking inputs, but I think this code can be further optimized. Give it a shot.

Edit 1:

```
import random

user_input = ""

turns = 5

print("Welcome to Advanced Hang Man!")

print("Use your brain to unscramble the word without seeing its order!")

words = ["hello","goolge","czar","gnat","relationship","victor","patric","gir","foo","cheese"]

random_word = (random.choice(words))

random_word_legnth = (len(random_word))

print("Hint! The length of the word is",random_word_legnth)

hold_random_word = [i for i in random_word]

# This condition can lead to issues in situations like this - abc and aabbcc [sorry couldn't quickly come up with a good actual example :)]
while turns != 0 and set(right_guess) != set(hold_random_word):

    user_input  = input("Please type your guess one letter at a time:").strip()

    right_guess = []
    wrong_guess = []

    #Calculating every input
    if len(user_input) == 1 and user_input.isalpha():
        # user_input is 1 letter so for i in user_input will execute only once
        # Use the if structure as defined above
        if user_input in hold_random_word:
            right_guess.append(i)
        else:
            # this is missing
            turns -= 1
            wrong_guess.append(i)
        print("Correct guess", ''.join(right_guess))
        print("Wrong guess", ''.join(wrong_guess))
    elif len(user_input) > 1:
        print("Please type only one letter at a time")
    elif not user_input.isalpha():
        print("Please enter only valid English letters")
    else:
        # handle this however you want :)
        pass
```

Comment: @CurrentlyVictor added few more suggestions, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your direct question is, but thinking about a hangman game you want to take the users guess and parse the entire word or phrase they are guessing to see if their guess matches anywhere in the word. I made a hang man game below that will function as expected (minus any error handling) Let me know if any parts confuse you, and i can explain

```
    import random
    wordcomp = []
    wordguess = []
#this is a word bank for all puzzles, they are randomly chosen
    word_bank = ['guess this phrase', 'Lagrange', 'foo', 'another phrase to guess']
    # This loop stores each letter in a list, and generates a blank list with correct spaces and blanks for user 
    rand_word = random.randrange(4) 
    for i in word_bank[rand_word]:
        wordcomp.append(i)
        if i == ' ':
            wordguess.append(' ')
        else:
            wordguess.append('__')
    print('I am thinking of a word,' , wordguess , ' it has ', len(wordguess), ' characters total, GOOD LUCK \n')
    wordlist = wordcomp    
    count = 0
    placeletter = 0
    wrongguess = []
    guesscount = 0
    while wordlist != wordguess:
        guess = input('please input a lower case letter within the english alphabet!') ##Check that input is one character, and lower case
        guesscount = guesscount + 1
        # This for loop scans through to see if the letter that was guessed is in the actual puzzle, and places in the correct spot!!
        for t in wordcomp:
            if t == guess:
                wordguess[placeletter] = guess
            placeletter = placeletter + 1
       # This check tells them they already guessed that letter... then makes fun of them
        if guess in wordguess:
            pass
        else:
            wrongguess.append(guess)
            while wrongguess.count(guess) > 1:
                wrongguess.remove(guess)
                print('you guessed the letter ' , guess , ' already, are you person that suffers short term memory loss...')
        print('The word I am thinking of: ' , wordguess)
        print('The letters you have already guess are: ', wrongguess)
        placeletter = 0
    # This tells them they finished the puzzle and the number of guesses it took, if its over 26, it calls them stupid for obvious reasons...
    if guesscount >= 26:
        print('you are an idiot if it took you more than 26 guesses..... now take a minute, sit silently, and think about why you are idiot if it took over 26 guesses... for hangman... where you guess the letters of the alphabet... YOU GET IT, stupid')
    elif guesscount < 26:
        print('Congrats you solved the puzzle, w00t!!')
```

Comment: Its important to output a list of blanks so the user can see and get an idea of the puzzle they are solving.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see